# Repeat or no-repeat of beckground image based on screem width

Tags: html, css, width, background-image, repeat

I am developing a webpage and encountered a problem. I have a (repeatable) background image, that looks good on screens of up to around 1200px  but not-so-good on much wider screens (>1600px+ or so). I want to set the repeat based on screen-width. How can it be done?

Thank you!

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: What kind of you have a background image. Please share.

Answer (score 0):

As commented, you should provide your code when asking such questions. You need [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries):

```
/* for 1200px+ */
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
    .myImageSelector: {
        background-repeat: repeat;
    }
}

/* for everything else */
.myImageSelector: {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to do it with css, You can know how much screen width is when your component renders. First you initialize  your states like this :

```
 const [
        windowSize,
        setWindowSize,
    ] = useState({
        width: 0,
        height: 0,
    })
```

then you can use this to listen to resize as well.

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {
        const updateSize = () => {
            setWindowSize({
                ...windowSize,
                height: window.innerHeight,
                width: window.innerWidth,
            })
        }
        window.addEventListener(`resize`, updateSize)
        updateSize()
        return () => window.removeEventListener(`resize`, updateSize)
    }, [])
```

once this is done, the state has the innerwidth of your webpage. So you can then use useeffect to listen to the change and render whatever you need accordingly.

```
useEffect(() => {
        if (windowSize.width > 1600) {
           // your code or logic here
        }
      
    }, [
       windowSize,
    ])
```